# problema con código python sencillo

Tags: python

se cae el código en la linea 4, que estoy haciendo mal?, su ayuda porfavor.

````py
contador=1

acumulador=0

while contador<=7:

  temp(contador) = int(input('ingrese temperatura: ')

  acumulador = acumulador + temp(contador)

  contador = contador + 1

  promedio = acumulador / 7

print(promedio)```
````

Comment: La variable temp no está declarada, ¿qué se supone que es? Porque, de primeras, parece una clase tuya; pero tiene pinta de que no.

Comment: falta cerrar un parentesis temp(contador) = int(input('ingrese temperatura: '))

Comment: Concuerdo con @RobertoPaillao , tienes un paréntesis mal cerrado. Ese es el error que te está marcando por ahora.

Answer (score 1):

Le di solucion sin usar arreglos, publico el codigo, espero ayude.

```
contador = 1
acumulador = 0

while contador <= 7:
    temp = int(input('ingrese temperatura ' + str(contador) + ": "))
    acumulador = acumulador + temp
    contador = contador + 1

promedio = acumulador / 7
print(str(promedio))
```

Comment: Puedes usar un `for _ in range(7)` en lugar del `while` y te evitas usar un contador.

Comment: `print(promedio)`; no necesitas hacer la conversión a string.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes asignar un input directamente a una función, es "ambiguo" temp(contador) es una función que procesa el valor que tiene en contador y a la vez quieres asignarle un valor
debes poner la asignación en diferentes líneas
y en la función temp debes tener un return del valor el cual si puedes asignar a una variable

En esta linea vuelves a llamar a la funcion temp
acumulador = acumulador + temp(contador).

```py
contador = int(input('ingrese temperatura: ')
valorRetornado = temp(contador)
acumulador = acumulador + valorRetornado
```

Comment: Hola Jose
```` temp(contador) = int(input('ingrese temperatura: ') ````
en esta linea lo que intento hacer es que las mediciones de temperatura se almacenen en TEMP pero en modo array, es por ello que coloco en parentesis el contador. asi es?

Comment: Los paréntesis se usan para llamar a funciones, los array se indican con corchetes lisos: []. Además, en esa línea te faltaría cerrar un paréntesis, `int ( input ( ... )` falta cerrar el paréntesis de `int(`

Answer (score 0):

En Python se favorece el uso de listas:

```
temp = []

while len(temp)<=7:
    temp.append(int(input('ingrese temperatura: ')))

promedio = sum(temp) / len(temp)
print(promedio)
```

`temp` es una lista (conocida como arreglo o vector en otros lenguajes). La sintaxis para listas usa el cuadrentesis (`[]`) para acceder a sus elementos; los paréntesis `()` se usan para llamar a funciones.

La línea

```
temp = []
```

inicializa una lista vacia.

Para controlar el número de elementos no necesito un contador separado; basta por preguntar por el largo (número de elementos) de la lista usando `len(temp)`.

Para agregar la temperatura al final de la lista, se usa `temp.append()`.

Una vez llena la lista con las temperaturas, puedo usar la función intrínsica `sum()`, que suma todos los valores dentro de la lista. Con eso, el calculo del promedio se reduce a dividir la suma por el largo de la lista.

#### Demo

```
temp = []

while len(temp)<=7:
    temp.append(int(input('ingrese temperatura: ')))

promedio = sum(temp) / len(temp)
print(promedio)
```

produce

```
ingrese temperatura: 4
ingrese temperatura: 5
ingrese temperatura: 6
ingrese temperatura: 7
ingrese temperatura: 8
ingrese temperatura: 93
ingrese temperatura: 3
ingrese temperatura: 2
16.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Versión ultracorta

```
temp = [int(input('ingrese temperatura: ')) for _ in range(7)]
print("Promedio: ", sum(temp) / len(temp))
```